# Safely cleanup apt-get after a failed R installation from an added repo

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I've tried to install a package, which failed. Now anytime I use apt-get, I get a long list of dpkg-errors. I've tried using `apt-get autoremove`, but I get the same pile of errors. Is there any safe way to clean this mess up?

```
(py3) ilia@arriam-lab2-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up r-base-core (3.3.2-1trusty0) ...
Preserving user changes to /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R (renamed from /etc/bash_completion.d/R)...
mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-boot:
 r-cran-boot depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-2trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-boot depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-boot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-cluster:
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-cluster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: depeNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                ndency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-foreign:
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-foreign (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-mass:
 r-cran-mass depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mass depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-mass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-kernsmooth:
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                          base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-cran-mass; however:
  Package r-cran-mass is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-kernsmooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-lattice:
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-lattice (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-nlme:
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.12-11.1); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-nlme (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-matrix:
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.12-11.1); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-matrix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-mgcv:
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-base-core; however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-cran-nlme; however:
  Package r-cran-nlme is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-cran-matrix; however:
  Package r-cran-matrix is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-mgcv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-survival:
 r-cran-survival depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.1-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-survival depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-survival depends on r-cran-matrix; however:
  Package r-cran-matrix is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-survival (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-rpart:
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-2trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-cran-survival; however:
  Package r-cran-survival is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-rpart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-class:
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-cran-mass; however:
  Package r-cran-mass is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-class (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-nnet:
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-nnet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-spatial:
 r-cran-spatial depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-spatial depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-spatial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-codetools:
 r-cran-codetools depends on r-base-core; however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-codetools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-recommended:
 r-recommended depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-boot (>= 1.2.19); however:
  Package r-cran-boot is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-cluster (>= 1.9.6-2); however:
  Package r-cran-cluster is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-foreign (>= 0.7-2); however:
  Package r-cran-foreign is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-kernsmooth (>= 2.2.14); however:
  Package r-cran-kernsmooth is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.10.11); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-mgcv (>= 1.1.5); however:
  Package r-cran-mgcv is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-nlme (>= 3.1.52); however:
  Package r-cran-nlme is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-rpart (>= 3.1.20); however:
  Package r-cran-rpart i
dpkg: error processing package r-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-base:
 r-base depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-base depends on r-recommended (= 3.3.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-recommended is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-base-dev:
 r-base-dev depends on r-base-core (>= 3.3.2-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-base-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-base-html:
 r-base-html depends on r-base-core; however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-base-html (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-base-core
 r-cran-boot
 r-cran-cluster
 r-cran-foreign
 r-cran-mass
 r-cran-kernsmooth
 r-cran-lattice
 r-cran-nlme
 r-cran-matrix
 r-cran-mgcv
 r-cran-survival
 r-cran-rpart
 r-cran-class
 r-cran-nnet
 r-cran-spatial
 r-cran-codetools
 r-recommended
 r-base
 r-base-dev
 r-base-html
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Update 1. What (and how) I tried to install.

```
echo "deb http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Update 2. Requested output

```
(py3) ilia@arriam-lab2-cpu:~$ ls -l /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R
ls: cannot access /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13596 nov.  1 04:17 /etc/bash_completion.d/R
```

Comment: what did you try to install and how ? See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've updated the question

Comment: @user.dz I've added the output

Comment: @EliKorvigo, copy that file using `sudo cp /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R` then `sudo apt-get -f install` . Then check again with `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I would file a bug report with the people who maintain the repo.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I sure will.

Comment: OMG, it is as if you read my mind!

Comment: @Vincent I'm glad you've found this thread useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- **Explaining the issue**

  > ```
  > Setting up r-base-core (3.3.2-1trusty0) ...
  > Preserving user changes to /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R (renamed from /etc/bash_completion.d/R)...
  > mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R’: No such file or directory
  > dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
  >  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
  > ```

  The post-installation script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst`) didn't check if `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R` file exist before trying to move it.
- **Quick fix / Workaround**

  1. Just create copy of the file.

     ```
     sudo cp /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R
     ```
  2. Fix the interrupted installation

     ```
     sudo apt-get -f install
     ```
- **Definitive fix**

  As bodhi.zazen said, raise a bug report to the project.

Comment: Is there a way I can send you flowers?

Comment: @Vincent, lol, :) Nice to hear that my answer helps you.